# Thevenin Voltage Problem

Tags: thevenin

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftQSgp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

How to get the Thevenin voltage if i remove the 10 ohm resistor?

Comment: Remove the 10 ohm resistance and apply superposition theorem.

Comment: Ok. After employing the superposition theorem, i find that 1/35 Amp current is flowing in the whole circuit. So how to get the Thevenin voltage?

Comment: now Thevenin voltage will be 5V - drop across R1.

Comment: But it could be drop across R3 also.

Comment: Isn't the drop across R1 is 50/35 V?

Comment: 3V + drop across R3 will also give the same answer. The drop across R3 is 20/35.

Comment: The Thevenin voltage must be somewhere between the two voltage sources. It cannot be higher than the highest one and in this circuit it cannot be lower than the lowest one. It must be somewhere in between, as you have a simple voltage divider in between the two sources.

Comment: @Sayans25 - Removing the 10 Ohm resistor means replacing it with open circuit. I am sure you will get necessary information in your text book. Firstly, you will require superposition theorem.

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove the 10Ω resistor;
2. Calculate the voltage at the nodes where the 10Ω resistor was connected;
3. Remove the voltage sources and calculate the equivalent resistance you see when you look into the circuit from the point where the 10Ω was connected.

> 2.1. Calculate the current through the circuit;
>  2.2. Calculate the voltage drop across one of the resistors;
>  2.3. Calculate the node voltage.

This looks like homework, so I'm not writing down exact formula's, rather indications.

bullet 2. Gets you the Thevenin voltage, somewhere half way between 3 and 4 Volt
bullet 3. Gets you the Thevenin resistance, somewhere around 15Ω

Now you do the math and give us the formula's and exact numbers.

Comment: Ok. The current through the circuit is 1/35 amp. So, voltage drop across the 50 ohm resistor is 50/35 amp. So, the node voltage is 5-(50/35)= 3.57 V= Thevenin voltage. And the 50 ohm and 20 ohm resistors are in parellel when viewed from the nodes. So, the Thevenin resistance is 14.28 ohm. Is that it? And you are right, this is homework!

Comment: Looks correct to me @Sayans25